# how to access 'keyless' anonymous hash

Tags: perl

My perl script produces a vairiable that has the following Data::Dumper output.

```
$VAR1 = [
  {
    'displayName' => 'unconfirmed',
    'tagName' => 'unconfirmed'
  },
  {
    'displayName' => 'new',
    'tagName' => 'new'
  },
  {
    'displayName' => 'started',
    'tagName' => 'started'
  },
  {
    'displayName' => 'reopened',
    'tagName' => 'reopened'
  },
  {
    'displayName' => 'resolved',
    'tagName' => 'resolved'
  }
];
```

The perl code to recreate this output looks like this:

```
my $foo = ([
  {
    'displayName' => 'unconfirmed',
    'tagName' => 'unconfirmed'
  },
  {
    'displayName' => 'new',
    'tagName' => 'new'
  },
  {
    'displayName' => 'started',
    'tagName' => 'started'
  },
  {
    'displayName' => 'reopened',
    'tagName' => 'reopened'
  },
  {
    'displayName' => 'resolved',
    'tagName' => 'resolved'
  }
]);
print Dumper($foo);
```

**Question A:** How can I access the content?

thanx for the help! Here's an example on how to access the structure.

```
for my $item (@{$foo}) {
    print $item->{tagName};
}
```

**Question B:** What is a good reference for the language context: hashes, arrays, meaning of different parenthesis, etc?

**Note:** The structure itself is at the end of several soap calls, xpath (`SOM->valueof`) and direct references (`$som->{tag1}->{tag2}`), yet I hope this question will be easier to ask and to answer.

Comment: You have a hash reference, not a hash without keys.

Comment: wow, that was fast! Thank you all.
updated the question with working code.

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Comment: I highly recommend [perldoc perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/reftut) which is the references tutorial. This easy to read document gives just a couple simple rules that help you understand and use references, especially in deep data structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl doesn't create keyless hashes. What you're looking at there with $foo is an array reference, so you'll have to do `print $foo->[$_]{displayName} for 0 .. $#{$foo}`.

And well, as for reference, you don't need that, you need a full-fledged intro text. Please refer to http://perl-tutorial.org

Comment: Thanx for the info link. Good site.

Answer (score 3):

**Answer A:**

Since you have used references (which are scalars) to the hashes and arrays, you should de-reference the scalar in order to access the Elements.

For example if you are willing to access 3rd hash, you'll access this as:

```
$foo->[2]->{"displayName"}; # accesses 'started'
$foo->[2]->{"tagName"}; # accesses 'started'
```

**Answer B:**

For references please refer [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: You comment broke the dam, thanx.

Comment: "references (which are scalars)", not the confusing "scalar references".  `\$x` is a scalar reference.

Comment: @ysth Made the changes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A good start for learning about complex Perl data structures like this is the [Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) which is included with every Perl installation (type `perldoc perldsc` on your command line).